# Anchor Tag behaving weird

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

My anchor tag is not working, the ideal url is localhost/VShroff/home/about.php however the url changes to localhost/about.php and is not redirected either. I have been trying to crack my head over this since a long time now.

The following is the HTML :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="generator"
    content="HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental) for Windows https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5/tree/c63cc39" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row" style="margin:10px;">
      <div id="blocka" class="column col-md-6" style="padding:20px;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:#DA0A82">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;" href="about.php">About</a>
          </li>
          <li id="family" class="family" style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Family</li>
          <li id="ent" class="ent" style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Enterprise</li>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">News &amp; Media</li>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Resources</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="familyNav" class="familyNav column col-md-6"
      style="margin-left:10px;padding:20px;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:#7D0651">
        <ul>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Timeline</li>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Tree</li>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Biographies</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="enterprise" class="enterprise column col-md-6"
      style="margin-left:10px;padding:20px;width:150px;height:150px;background-color:#7D0651">
        <ul>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Parimal K. Shroff &amp; Co.</li>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Sunways Group</li>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">Organograms</li>
          <li style="font-family:perpetua;font-size:16px;color:white;">The Shroffice</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Im using the following Jquery and CSS :

```
<script>
$('.family').click(function () {
    $('#enterprise').hide(); 
    $('#familyNav').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
$('.ent').click(function () {
    $('#familyNav').hide(); 
    $('#enterprise').slideToggle('2000',"swing", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
</script>

<style>
#blocka {
    z-index: 100;
}
#familyNav {
    display:none;
}
#family {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#enterprise {
    display: none;
}
#ent {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
```

Edit : When I hover my mouse over the link, it shows the correct url (localhost/directories/about.php) However when I click on it nothing happens but the browser url changes to localhost/about.php ( The page is not redirected to localhost/about.php)

Comment: Might you have a `<base href>` tag?

Comment: about menu anchor tag is not working or other menu ?

Comment: None of the tags are working. And nope I dont have any base href

Comment: Weird issue then... Using any sort of mod rewrite?

Comment: Nope no mod rewrite, im pretty confused myself

Comment: So where is the rest of your Javascript code? Are you using external scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JQuery file has beeb causing this error, couldn't refine and find out what was the problem, however on removing the jquery file it worked normally.

I think I can do without that file.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your directory structure as

```
htdocs or www (BASED ON YOUR SERVER)
|
|--Vshroff
      |--NEW
          |--home
             |
             |-index.php(HERE IS THE ANCHOR TAG)
             |-about.php
```

So I created same structure on my machine.
Here are the files

index.php

```
<?php
echo '<a href="about.php">about</a>';
?>
```

about.php

```
<?php
echo '<a href="index.php">index</a>';
?>
```

It it works perfect.

Comment: tell us the directory structure where this HTML code is present.

Comment: Tried /about.php no luck.
Directory : localhost/Vshroff/New/home/

Comment: @AadityaDamani There is no point giving full url in the anchor tag.. Alright.. Let me correct it again.

Comment: @AadityaDamani on what page is the current anchor tag written?

Comment: The directory is correct. Anchor tag is written in index.php in same directory

Comment: I created the same directory structure and tested it.. It works only as about.php and not with / before it.

Comment: I think the problem is with the css file ive used, which is app.min.css

Answer (score 0):

if you have this HTML in `www` directory then it will redirect to `localhost/about.php` . If its present in`www/shroff/home/` then it will redirect relatively to `localhsot/shroff/home/about.php`

Comment: i guess the code you provided is in the same folder as the `about.php` . If that's the case then it should work correctly.

Comment: The code I provided is in the same folder, doesnt work yet

Comment: did you use `url rewrite` or `routing` in some code? 

[.htaccess route with mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a relative path like : "./about.php" if your about page is in the same folder as index... ?

Comment: did you try your page without your javascript code? (just comment it and try again)

Comment: ... Maybe clear your browser cache? and what about your html code? is it valid? did you check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work....

```
<?php
    $root='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $root;?>/about.php">About</a>
```